# How to extend table height (or width) so border shows at different location

Tags: css

I have a table who's height is determined by how many rows are pulled back from a query.  I'd like to have the table have a bottom border that's visible some pixels below the last line of data.

I've tried adding margin or padding to the bottom of the table so that the bottom border line is lower.  Here is what I have now:

```
#shots_table{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 780px;
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

What the output looks like:

[image]

How do I push the line above lower?

Comment: Which browser are you having a problem with, because the code in question works fine in Chrome. The `padding` is pushing the bottom border down, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try increasing the `padding-bottom` on the last row's cells:

```
#shots_table tr:last-child>td {padding-bottom:20px}
```